# Adding ids Dynamic on click at each div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an input field with some fixed value and I have some div's with same class name and different ids. So I am trying when I press the div to add each id in my fixed value into my input field.

For example:

```
<input name="yourcode" type="text" id="yourcode" value="http://www.domain.com/myfile.php?ids=" />
```

So when I press each div I want to add the id by comma seperated in my input value.

e.g

```
<input name="yourcode" type="text" id="yourcode" value="http://www.domain.com/myfile.php?ids=1,2,3,4,5,6" />
```

My `<div>'s` look like:

```
<div class="s" id="1"></div>
<div class="s" id="2"></div>
<div class="s" id="3"></div>
<div class="s" id="4"></div>
<div class="s" id="5"></div>
```

I am using the code below to grab the clicked div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".s").click(function () {
        var theid = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(theid);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is to display all clicked div's id in the input field or you are not getting the ids using the above code ?

Comment: Use $.on insted of $selector.click().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ids = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".s").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(ids.indexOf(id) === -1) {
           ids.push(id);
           $('#yourcode').val("http://www.domain.com/myfile.php?ids=" + ids.toString());
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var clickedIDs = "";
        $(".s").click(function(){
            clickedIDs += $(this).attr("id");
            alert(clickedIDs);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Currently you are just alerting current clicked id. This will append current clicked id to previous clicked ids' string and alert that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: just wondering why this is not the accepted answer.any reasons irene T?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".s").click(function(){
    var theid = $(this).attr("id");
    var currentVal = $('yourInputfield').val();
    $('yourInputfield').val(currentVal+','+theid );
});
```